# Kendo Splitter Initializes with zero size

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, splitter

I am using a kendo splitter with knockout-kendo.js.

Upon load, the splitter has all size parameters showing zero.  Only after clicking on the splitter bar, does it set the proper size.

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use a work around. Upon opening a page, issue

```
$("#your_splitter").data("kendoSplitter").trigger("resize");
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I am actually using this trick, however, I am also using Durandal/Hottowel template with transition which fades and slides the view.  And re-size causes an abrupt change in the presentation.

Comment: $("#splitter").fadeIn().resize();
took care of the transition